# Unable to output multiplication of values from textboxes (possibly NAN) - Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

i am trying to understand Backbone.js and how it works. i have created two textboxes that takes any values, and onclick of button(Multipy) the values are displayed in the boxes below, which works but i want the multiplication of two values to be shown in the third box - i tried to assign the both values to variables and multiply but it doesn't seems to work. i think there is some problem with the returned value from textboxes, think it is NAN. Anyway please have a look and advise. i have commented out the code that is not working.
live url : http://egoless.co.uk/learning/learn_backbone/first-backbone-app.php

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
    <title>Testing</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="underscore.js">
  </script><script type="text/javascript" src="backbone.js"></script>
  <style>
  .size {
    width: 100px;
    height: 30px;
    border: solid 1px red;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <input type="text" id="box1" />
  &nbsp;
  <input type="text" id="box2" />
  &nbsp;
  <button id="myBtn">Multiply</button>
  <br>
  <br>
  <div id="myBox" class="size"></div>
  <div id="myBox2" class="size"></div>
  <div id="myBox3" class="size"></div>

  <script>

  (function($){
  //defining model 1
    PersonModel1 = Backbone.Model.extend({

      defaults:{
              age : function(){

               return  $("input#box1").val();

              }
          }
    });

    myPerson1 = new PersonModel1();

    //defining model 2
    PersonModel2 = Backbone.Model.extend({

      defaults:{
              age : function(){

               return $("input#box2").val();

              }
      }
    });

    myPerson2 = new PersonModel2();

    //defining collection


    Group = Backbone.Collection.extend({
          Model: PersonModel1,
          Model: PersonModel2,
          url:"#"

      })

          People = new Group([]);
          People.add(myPerson1);
          People.add(myPerson2);  

    //adding view

    ResultView = Backbone.View.extend({
          el:'button',
          events:{
              'click':'render'
          },
        render:function(){

          val1 = myPerson1.get('age');
          val2 = myPerson2.get('age')
          val3 = val1*val2 // not working
          $('div#myBox').html(val1);
          $('div#myBox2').html(val2);
          $('div#myBox3').html(val3); // not working
          $('input#box1').val("");
          $('input#box2').val("");
          return this;
          }
      })




    $(document).ready(function(e) {
       myResultView = new ResultView();
    });

  })(jQuery);

  </script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Start by tracing as close to the bottom as you can. Put a `console.log($("input#box1").val())` in the age method where you try and get the value. If that comes through as a correct number keep moving up the stack with traces until you find the problem. If it isn't correct there then you know you have a problem with your selector or the element and you can test and adjust or move down from there.

Comment: Also you should use `var` when defining your variables in your View or you are going to have scope problems in the future not to mention the possibility of it getting deleted by accident.

Comment: yes this works console.log(($("input#box1").val())*($("input#box2").val())) but i am trying to assign the values to the properties of an object defined as a Model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in defaults section of model definition you can only assign value to the attributes.
to return value age you should write separate function.

```
          defaults:{},
          age : function(){
           return  $("input#box1").val();
          }
```

and you can call like this

```
      val1 = myPerson1.age();
      val2 = myPerson2.age();
      val3 = val1*val2 ;
```

Comment: i tried using parseInt and also + but than it doesn't show any value at all

Comment: try to check always what the values are/is being returned using `console.log(val1,val2,val3)`

Comment: Cheers - sorry i won't be able to click arrow up for your answer as i am new to stackoverflow and hasn't gained enough reputation to arrow up for my own questions.